# Не работает фильтр для состояний в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

В aiogram квиз-боте я пытаюсь создать кастомный фильтр, который возвращает True, если пользователь находится в одном из нескольких состояний. Ответы от пользователя я получаю с помощью inline клавиатуры и результаты каждого вопроса записываю в FSM (так ведь можно делать?). Вот код хендлеров, в которых начинаются проблемы:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="choice")
async def choice_continent(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.edit_text("Выберите континент, по столицам странам которого "
                                     "будет проводиться тест ")
    await callback.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=choice_menu)

    await Test.first()


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains="choice_continent", state=Test.start)
async def start_test(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    continent = callback.data.split(":")[-1]
    countries = data[continent]

    await callback.message.edit_text(f"Выбран континент: <b>{continent}</b> ⛰")
    await callback.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=start_menu)

    await state.update_data(continent=continent, countries=countries)

    await Test.next()


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="back", state=Test.Q1)
async def back_to_menu(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await choice_continent(callback)


@dp.callback_query_handler(IsInStatesGroup(), text="start_question")
async def start_question(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    data_test = await state.get_data()
    countries = data_test["countries"]

    country = str(random.choice(list(countries.keys())))

    await callback.message.edit_text(f"<b>Выберите столицу страны: {country}.</b>")
    await callback.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=await create_question_menu(country, countries))

    await state.update_data(country=country, countries=countries)
    await Test.next()
```

Мне нужно из choice_continent переходить в start_test, при нажатии на кнопку отмены переходить в back_to_menu, а из start_test в start_question. Вот код inline-клавиатур:

```
choice_callback_data = CallbackData("choice_continent", "continent")
question_callback_data = CallbackData("question", "type", "capital")

continents = list(data.keys())

main_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
main_menu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Выбрать континент ", callback_data="choice"))

choice_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()

for name in continents:
    choice_menu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text=name, callback_data=choice_callback_data.new(
        continent=name
    )))

start_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
start_menu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Начать тест ✏", callback_data="start_question"))
start_menu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад ⬅", callback_data="back"))

next_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
next_menu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Дальше ➡", callback_data="next_question"))
```

Вот класс с группой состояний:

```
class Test(StatesGroup):
    start = State()
    Q1 = State()
    Q2 = State()
    Q3 = State()
    Q4 = State()
    Q5 = State()
    Q6 = State()
    Q7 = State()
    Q8 = State()
    Q9 = State()
    Q10 = State()
```

Вот класс кастомного фильтр:

```
class IsInStatesGroup(BoundFilter):

    async def check(self, callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
        state_name = await state.get_state()

        return state_name in Test.all_states_names[1:]
```

Так я его подключаю:

```
if __name__ == "filters":
    dp.filters_factory.bind(IsInStatesGroup)
```

Если что, я в loader файл при создании диспатчера передал объект MemoryStorage, а при импорте в app файле придерживался правильного порядка: filters, middlewares, handlers. Когда я просто в хендлере делаю фильтр state=Test.Q1 - всё работает. Что делать?

Comment: Проверьте, подключается ли он вообще? Сделайте принт

Comment: <filters.states_group_filter.IsInStatesGroup object at 0x00000215A4613430> - это выдаёт.

Comment: И это, если без скобок <class 'filters.states_group_filter.IsInStatesGroup'>.

Comment: Это в if __name__ == "filters":?

Comment: if __name__ == "filters": если точнее.

Comment: Если же вы имели ввиду где я вызывал print() с фильтром - в handler'е.

Comment: Нет, я хочу чтобы вы вызвали его именно в этом if name == "filters"

Comment: <filters.states_group_filter.IsInStatesGroup object at 0x000001E2D3F64A30>

Comment: Вызвал в нём со ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри. Я не сильно уверен, но сделал то что точно работает.

```
class FSM_TEST(StatesGroup):
    Q1 = State()
    Q2 = State()


class Filter_(BoundFilter):
    async def check(self, message: types.Message):
        state = dp.current_state(chat=message.chat.id, user=message.from_user.id)
        cur_state = await state.get_state()
        return cur_state in FSM_TEST.all_states_names


@dp.message_handler()
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Приве1т.")
    await FSM_TEST.Q1.set()


@dp.message_handler(Filter_(), state="*")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Приве2т.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
    dp.filters_factory.bind(Filter_)
```

Я не смог получить обьект state в фильтре, пришлось получать его через экземпляр диспатчера. Ты только поменяй с месседжа на колбек. Я думаю что он у тебя не забиндился, где бы он у тебя это не делал.
К слову, я не совсем понимаю зачем ради такой мелочи делать целый кастомный фильтр.

Comment: Это да, я уже понял, что можно было просто сделать в фильтрах state=Test.all_states)

Comment: Но всё равно спасибо, может пригодится в будущем)