# Как в aiogram получить данные с прошлого состояния, не зная его названия

Tags: python, aiogram

Я пытаюсь сделать квиз-бота, в котором варианты ответов на вопросы будут присылаться в виде inline-клавиатур:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="choice")
async def choice_continent(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.edit_text("Выберите континент, по столицам странам которого "
                                     "будет проводиться тест ")
    await callback.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=choice_menu)

    await Test.first()


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains="choice_continent", state=Test.start)
async def start_test(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    continent = callback.data.split(":")[-1]
    countries = data[continent]

    await callback.message.edit_text(f"Выбран континент: <b>{continent}</b> ⛰")
    await callback.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=start_menu)

    async with state.proxy() as data_test:
        data_test["continent"] = continent
        data_test["countries"] = countries

    await Test.next()


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="back", state=Test.Q1)
async def back_to_menu(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await choice_continent(callback)


@dp.callback_query_handler(IsInStatesGroup(), text="start_question")
async def start_question(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    data_test = await state.get_data()
    countries = data_test["countries"]

    country = str(random.choice(list(countries.keys())))

    await callback.message.edit_text(f"<b>Выберите столицу страны: {country}.</b>")
    await callback.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=await create_question_menu(country, countries))

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["country"] = country
        data["countries"] = countries

    await Test.next()
```

А вот inline-клавиатуры:

```
data = continents_data

choice_callback_data = CallbackData("choice_continent", "continent")
question_callback_data = CallbackData("question", "type", "capital")

continents = list(data.keys())

main_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
main_menu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Выбрать континент ", callback_data="choice"))

choice_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()

for name in continents:
    choice_menu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text=name, callback_data=choice_callback_data.new(
        continent=name
    )))

start_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
start_menu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Начать тест ✏", callback_data="start_question"))
start_menu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад ⬅", callback_data="back"))

next_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
next_menu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Дальше ➡", callback_data="next_question"))


async def create_question_menu(country, countries):
    question_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    capital = countries[country]
    capitals = []

    for country in random.sample(list(countries.keys()), 2):
        capitals.append(countries[country])

    capitals.append(capital)

    random.shuffle(capitals)

    for variant in capitals:
        if variant == capital:
            question_menu.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=variant, callback_data=question_callback_data.new(
                type="correct", capital=variant
            )))
        else:
            question_menu.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=variant, callback_data=question_callback_data.new(
                type="incorrect", capital=variant
            )))

    return question_menu
```

Класс группы состояний:

```
class Test(StatesGroup):
    start = State()
    Q1 = State()
    Q2 = State()
    Q3 = State()
    Q4 = State()
    Q5 = State()
    Q6 = State()
    Q7 = State()
    Q8 = State()
    Q9 = State()
    Q10 = State()
```

Мне нужно из choice_continent переходить в start_test, из start_test либо в back_to_menu, либо в start_question. Ну так вот - мне практически всегда нужно получать данные, записанные в предыдущее состояние. Как мне сделать, так, чтобы я моg скажем из start_question в состоянии Q9 (IsInStatesGroup - это мой кастомный фильтр, который проверяет, есть ли state в группе моих стейтов начиная с Q1) получить данные из состояния Q8, который я записал раннее. (без перехода в дополнительные хэндлеры)?

Comment: Какие именно данные вы хотите получить? То что ввел юзер?

Comment: Я хочу вытащить из прошлого состояния список с одним удалённым элементом.

Comment: А вы этот список где-то храните?

Comment: Который удаляется во время того, как пользователь нажимает на кнопку с ответом.

Comment: Список храню в актуальном state и хочу передавать его (список) следующему.

Comment: Может мне более подробно описать логику работы бота?

Comment: Простите что? Что значит актуальный стейт? Если вы не делаете state.finish или state.reset_state(with_data=True) то data у вас не будет меняться

Comment: Если же вы полностью стираете данные из стейта, то уже никак вы их не получите.

Comment: Вроде как, в вашем коде, вы явно не стираете данные, так что я думаю они будут лежать в state.proxy

Comment: Тогда извините за глупый вопрос, я просто впервые FSM использую.

Comment: Все это делают впервые =) Просто знайте что при смене стейта, данные не стираются, только при finish или reset_state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При смене стейта, данные в data стейта, не стираются до тех пор когда вы не сделаете `state.finish` или `state.reset_state(with_data=True)`.

Comment: Я видимо когда тестил FSM, не правильно понял концепцию передачи данных в стейтах. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: И если не затруднит - можете помочь со второй проблемой? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1422069/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-aiogram